resizeEvent keeps on retriggering
I have a problem when I try to do some dynamic adjustments on my window or in my screen resolution.
Inside resizeEvent I'm doing this:
     def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        
        # Calculate button height dynamically based on the window's height
        button_height = self.height() // 15 
        button_width = self.width() // 2
        
        # Set dynamic size for buttons
        self.scan_button.setFixedHeight(button_height)
        self.pause_button.setFixedHeight(button_height)
        self.settings.setFixedHeight(button_height)
        self.saveCSV.setFixedHeight(button_height)
        self.savePNG.setFixedHeight(button_height)

        # Optionally, adjust button widths proportionally
        self.scan_button.setFixedWidth(button_width)
        self.pause_button.setFixedWidth(button_width)
        self.settings.setFixedWidth(button_width)
        self.saveCSV.setFixedWidth(button_width)
        self.savePNG.setFixedWidth(button_width)

The thing is, when I try to run it, it triggers a re-render in a loop. Also, this happens after a specific value is exceeded (for my case the value 2 it will trigger a re-render but the value of 3 will not in my button_width).
Some of my UI widgets inside my init:
        # ============================== Create a Grid Layout for the Buttons ==============================
        button_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.scan_button = QPushButton("Scan")
        self.pause_button = QPushButton("Pause")
        self.settings = QPushButton("Settings")
        self.saveCSV = QPushButton("Save CSV")
        self.savePNG = QPushButton("Save PNG")

        self.pause_button.setVisible(False)

        button_layout.addWidget(self.scan_button, 0, 0)  # Row 0, Column 0
        button_layout.addWidget(self.pause_button, 0, 0)  # Row 0, Column 1
        button_layout.addWidget(self.settings, 1, 0)  # Row 0, Column 1
        button_layout.addWidget(self.saveCSV, 0, 1)  # Row 0, Column 1
        button_layout.addWidget(self.savePNG, 1, 1)  # Row 0, Column 1

        layout.addLayout(button_layout, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)


Layout managers need to adapt to the widgets they manage, including their size restraints (like minimum/fixed sizes): if those restraints change, the layout may decide it needs more space, and therefore force a further resize event. There's your recursion. Setting minimum sizes on a resize event and based on the new size is almost always discouraged when layout managers are in use, so just don't do that. Instead clarify what you exactly need to do, and carefully check the layout managers documentation (starting by stretch factors).

Im trying to make my buttons adapt with the screen size ,for example in my resolution 1920x1080 everyting working fine but if i change in a resolution lets say 1280x720 my buttons are overflowing (and also many other widgets). So in general im trying to make my widgets responsive .

So i dont need the resizeEvent at all? Just to put a minimum or a maximum with-height?

Layouts already take care of setting ("make responsive", in modern terms) the geometries of all the widgets they manage, considering the size hint and policies each widget has and the available size, and they do that whenever the widget they're set on is resized. So, no, you should not override resizeEvent() at all, in principle, and just let the layout manager do its job. You should also be very careful in setting minimum and/or maximum sizes. You're having a clear case of XY problem: asking the wrong question because you're fixing the wrong problem.

Your real problem is about your original layout, which may need adjustments and/or because you are using minimum sizes to begin with even when they're not necessary: you probably want to ensure that the window is not too small if the screen allows it, but forcing minimum/fixed sizes of child widgets is not the solution. I suggest you to either edit your question by adding a proper [mre] including your layout, explaining your actual size requirements (for the window, and/or widget proportions) and the issues you have with those, or delete this post and create a new one addressing all that.

Sorry to say this but this is not helping at all ... i just comment my real problem and you just say about minimal example ... i already clarified this ,i dont know what else will help.The problem is general about my screen size and my widget size i want to make it responsive for all screen sizes not something specific .

As told, layout managers will take care of resizing and adapting widget geometries whenever their window is resized. If you need specific proportions, you must properly set stretch factors in the layout (or in the widget size policies). And, yes, we need a more comprehensive example, especially because you specifically wrote that you have issues with other widgets as well, and we don't know the overall structure of the whole window, which is fundamental to understand the behavior, and is exactly what layouts do. Please do read the above link about layouts, and also experiment with Qt Designer.
